# Set the width of a Html Helper drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've several ways of doing it like this, to no avail:

```
<div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DropDownListFor("ManufacturerId", String.Empty, new { style="width:500px" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)
     </div>
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: The `DropDownListFor` method takes a lambda expression as its first parameter. Did you mean to use `DropDownList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),  
    new { @style = "width: 500px;" })
```

Answer (score 2):

The general gist of what you're doing should work, but it looks like your arguments may be a little confused. How about:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
    new{ style="width: 500px;"})
```

Comment: I was using @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", String.Empty) originally. I'm still getting an invalid argument when I add the style part.

Comment: @MissioDei: Try adding a `null` argument as the second argument. You were passing `string.Empty` as the `optionLabel` argument, but in other overloads of the method that argument comes after the `selectList` argument. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx for a full list of correct overload signatures, and make sure the arguments you're passing match up.